# Stack Overflow query to select questions with 3 or more answers

Tags: sql, stackexchange-api

When using the [stack overflow data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new), how can I select questions with 3 or more answers?

Comment: In your question "the corresponding answers"...do you mean "Accepted Answer Id" in the Table or all answers in each question? Would you explain more?

Answer (score 2):

There's an `AnswerCount` field on the Posts table:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE AnswerCount >= 3 AND PostTypeId = 1
```

Comment: Thanks . How do i select the corresponding answers as well.?

Comment: With a JOIN. But you need to the filter the results more. This will pull quite a large amount of data back, and the data explorer limits you to 50,000 rows.

Comment: Sounds like you need a basic SQL tutorial. That's out of scope here.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the number of answers on the left side of the question. the number in green box is the number of correct answers.